# regular expression to exclude comments

Tags: replace, unix

I am trying to use grep -v -e '' to exclude comments (lines with # as the first non-whitespace character) from a file.
The # can appear either at the begining of the line or there could be a combination of several blank space and tabs in any combination before the first # is encountered.

Assume the file np4 contains this:

```
# hash at the begining of the line
## two hashes at the begining of the line
#### four hashes at the begining of the line
  # two white spaces then a hash
a good line
    another good line starting with a few spaces
                         a good line starting with a combination of spaces and tabs
                # two white spaces, two tabes and then a hash
                  ## two tabs, two white spaces and then two hashes
            # tab, ws, tab, ws, tab then hash
```

I tried using the command below, but it does not work as I thought it would. I should only get three lines as the output.

grep -v -e '^\s*#.*$' np4

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are missing is the plus sign to match one or more of the pound symbol. I didn't grep as i tested, but this looked good. i've supplied a permalink to my test.

^\s*#+.*$

[Here is a permalink to the test on regexpal.com.](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%5Cs%2a%23%2B.%2a%24&input=%23%20hash%20at%20the%20begining%20of%20the%20line%0A%23%23%20two%20hashes%20at%20the%20begining%20of%20the%20line%0A%23%23%23%23%20four%20hashes%20at%20the%20begining%20of%20the%20line%0A%20%20%23%20two%20white%20spaces%20then%20a%20hash%0Aa%20good%20line%0A%20%20%20%20another%20good%20line%20starting%20with%20a%20few%20spaces%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20good%20line%20starting%20with%20a%20combination%20of%20spaces%20and%20tabs%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20two%20white%20spaces%2C%20two%20tabes%20and%20then%20a%20hash%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%23%20two%20tabs%2C%20two%20white%20spaces%20and%20then%20two%20hashes%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20tab%2C%20ws%2C%20tab%2C%20ws%2C%20tab%20then%20hash)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if \s works well for grep. 
Could you try  "^[   ]*#.*"  ?
In the [] there is a space and a tab, two characters.